# Assigning a boolean value to a blank series in a pandas data frame based on a count of values in a string in another series/

Tags: python, pandas, loops, boolean, assign

I want to assign a boolean value to a currently column of "True" if the first column contains only one period and "False" if it contains more than one period.

This is what I've gotten to at this point and I am completely stuck:

```
for index, row in qbstats.iterrows():
    if qbstats['qb'].count(".") > 1
```

...... so if it's greater than one I want to assign the column labeled `"num_periods_in_name"` as `False` else wise it sets as `True`.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where()`:

```
df['New Col'] = np.where(df['qb'].str.count('\.')>1, False, True)
```

Note, you will need to escape the `.` with a `\` as well.

Below is an example:

```
            qb
0       Hello.
1    helloo...
2  hello...ooo
3       Hell.o
```

And applying the code above gives:

```
            qb  New Col
0       Hello.     True
1    helloo...    False
2  hello...ooo    False
3       Hell.o     True
```